# User is unable to see the opportunity records even though profile is having View All Data Permission?

Tags: sharing

User is unable to see the opportunity records even though profile is having View All Data Permission?

Any Help is appriciated.

Comment: The user can't see any Opportunities? Or just some Opportunities? Any message when they try and access an Opportunity record?

Comment: What have you tried or checked so far? Generally you should start with the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind that Opportunity is a child of Account. If a user cannot see all Accounts, they cannot see all Opportunities. You'll have to verify their access to account as this is a master detail relationship.